# Python: Compute percentage change for every column in MultiIndex DataFrame in conjunction with groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe where I need to compute the percentage change column-wise. I used `apply` in conjunction with pd.pct_change. This is working as long I don't take into consideration the outer level of the MultiIndex with `groupby`.

```
# Creat pd.MultiIndex and include some NaNs

rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-12-20', periods=20, name='date')
date = np.concatenate([rng, rng])
perm = np.array([*np.repeat(1, 20), *np.repeat(2, 20)])

d = {'perm': perm,
     'date': date,
     'ser_1': np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=[40]),
     'ser_2': np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=[40])}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.iloc[5:8, 2:] = np.nan
df.iloc[11:13, 2] = np.nan
df.iloc[25:28, 2:] = np.nan
df.iloc[33:37, 3] = np.nan

df.set_index(['perm', 'date'], drop=True, inplace=True)


# Apply pd.pct_change to every column individually in order to take care of the
# NaNs at different positions. Also, use groupby for every 'perm'. This one is
# where I am struggling.

# This is working properly, but it doesn't take into account 'perm'. The first
# two rows of perm=2 (i.e. rows 20 and 21) must be NaN.
chg = df.apply(lambda x, periods:
               x.dropna().pct_change(periods=2).
               reindex(df.index, method='ffill'),
               axis=0, periods=2)

# This one is causing an error:
# TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
chg = df.groupby('perm').apply(lambda x, periods:
                               x.dropna().pct_change(periods=2).
                               reindex(df.index, method='ffill'),
                               axis=0, periods=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The " *unexpected keyword argument 'axis'* " error comes from the fact that [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) are two different methods, with similar but different parameters: they have the same name because they are intended to perform a very similar task, but they belong to two different classes.
If you check the documentation, you'll see that the first one require an `axis` parameter. The second one not.

So to have a working code with `groupby`, just remove the `axis` parameter from `GroupBy.apply`. Since you want to work column by column because of `dropna`, you need to use `DataFrame.apply` inside `GroupBy.apply`:

```
chg = df.groupby('perm').apply(lambda x:
                           x.apply(lambda y : y.dropna().pct_change(periods=2)
                           .reindex(x.index, method='ffill'),
                           axis=0))
```

This produces what you want (first two rows of "perm 2" are `NaN`, other numbers are equal to the result you get by using `apply` without `groupby`).
Note that I've also edit the first argument in `reindex`: is `x.index` and not `df.index` otherwise you'll get a double `perm` index in the final result.

Final note, no need to pass a `period` argument to the `lambda` function if you are setting it hardcoded in `pc_change`. Is redundant.

Comment: You're right, your suggestion doesn't lead to the above mentioned error message. However, the solution doesn't seem to be correct. The lambda function receives the complete dataframe rather than individual columns. That's problematic when applying `dropna`. Take a look at ser_2 at 2018-12-31 and 2019-01-01. These values will be deleted due to the fact that ser_1 has NaNs at these dates. That screws up the percentage change for ser_2. I understand that the `axis` argument is not available, but I need something like that to get the correct solution.

Comment: I see. Then you could use `Data.Frame.apply` into `GroupBy.apply`. I'm going to edit my answer.